# Android activity Binary XML file line : You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, android-layout

I've read about it already, but still it's here.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".TaskEditActivity" >
```

So, the exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #34: You must supply a layout_width attribute.`

Attribute is there, schema too...
Solution?

Comment: clean and rebuild? And post the whole layout

Comment: I am sure that one of the child views in your layout will be missing a layout width attribute.. please cross check,,

Comment: Can you post your entire XML file please?

Answer (score 61):

Also i recommend **check your dimens**. You may have layout width in dimens, you go to it and you have **value like "150" not "150dp" (missing dp)** also cause this (that was my case)

Comment: I had the width in dimens, but everything is there and correct, and it's happening occasionally not always

Comment: Thanks man you save my day. It took me 2 days searching for this bug

Comment: Thanks for your input. It is a hard to find run-time-only error and hard to notice as well.

Answer (score 8):

I had a dimension for a given width but it wasn't present in the default *dimens.xml*

```
res/
   values-w320dp/
          dimens.xml -> ring_radius=5dp
   values/
          dimens.xml -> missing ring_radius
```

Comment: which device you saw this?

Comment: which device you saw this?Isn't this weird and completely contradictory to smallest width configuration. It should have picked righteously from 320 dp.

Answer (score 6):

It's clear. Child elements missed `layout_width` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was having an extra attribute on one of my view groups (scrollview):

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

After that there was I forgot to change my casting of EditText to TextView:

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText**

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not in this layout element, its on the inner one, take a look at line number 34. There is is another user interface element that lacks the **layout_width** attribute.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if you apply or don't apply the **correct theme on a fragment/activity**.

For example Leanback's `OnboardingSupportFragment` requires `Theme.Leanback.Onboarding`, which you have to apply either on the activity in the manifest `android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback.Onboarding"` or in the fragment overriding `onProvideTheme()`

```
@Override
public int onProvideTheme() {
    return R.style.Theme_Leanback_Onboarding;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, inside one of my layout.xml files, I had

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_1_col_0"
    android:layout_width="@string/default_picture_size"
    android:layout_height="@string/default_picture_size"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/tile"
    android:onClick="mClickMethod" >
</ImageView>
```

and inside strings.xml, I had 
wrap_content

and so it was showing this in Android Studio:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_1_col_0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/tile"
    android:onClick="mClickMethod" >
</ImageView>
```

I thought everything would work because there were no errors and the application compiled and ran. However, there was a run time error that said I didn't set the layout_width.

Once I changed layout_width and layout_height from:

```
android:layout_width="@string/default_picture_size"
android:layout_height="@string/default_picture_size"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

just incase all the solutions don't work
`clean project` -> `run`
cheers